# .NET sql connections exceeding max pool size

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

I wrote a simple app to test Max Pool Size=50 in the connection string.

```
    static void Test1()
    {
        string connectionString = @"Server=.;Database=appsdb;Trusted_Connection=True;Application Name=JH;Max Pool Size=50";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select newid()", conn))
            {
                using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"[{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] {i} - {r.GetGuid(0)}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I had it run for 51 connections initially **expecting the 51st connection to fail but it did not.**
It is consistently failing at **71st** connection with the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.'

When I check with `sp_who` (or `sp_who2`) I can see that there are exactly **50** connections. This is baffling.
I can understand if .NET is somehow letting you reuse the connections **but why at 71st?**
Why only allow extra 20 (logical) connections? Why not 19 or 47?

Comment: I've reformatted your text to make the question more clear. Initially I thought your question was about "why is it failing?", I had to read it twice to figure out you are really asking "why is it failing **at this specific point**?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're not holding the connections between iterations of the `for` loop. That means that every time you iterate through the `for` loop, the connection from the previous iteration is eligible for garbage collection, which will release the *underlying* connection back to the pool. So: presumably garbage collection happened. To test this: keep the used connections reachable - put them in a list or similar. For example:

```
var list = new List<SqlConnection>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    list.Add(conn);
    conn.Open();
    // ... etc removed
}
GC.KeepAlive(list);
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that in the time the loop runs, the garbage collector collects 20 connections consistently, releasing them back to the connection pool thus enabling the loop to run up to 71 connections, right?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'm saying it is a viable hypothesis that fits the code shown, and can be investigated with simple tweaks that I have shown

Comment: @MarcGravell Garbage collection was it - I don't know why I missed that in the first place. Thanks!